# Disable SSL on HttpClient with PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to disable SSL on my `CloseableHttpAsyncClient`. Below is the code I use:

```
private synchronized CloseableHttpAsyncClient getCloseableClient() throws Exception {
    if (closeableHttpAsyncClient == null) {
        logger.info("New Async Client created ");
        closeableHttpAsyncClient = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(createConnConfig())
                .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                .setSSLContext(new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean isTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }).build())
                // .setKeepAliveStrategy(kepAliveStrategy) TODO
                .setConnectionManager(createPoolingConnManager()).build();

        closeableHttpAsyncClient.start();
    }
    return closeableHttpAsyncClient;
}
```

However when I run the above I still get:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
```

What could be wrong here, I assume I have to modify my `PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager` as well. However I am not aware of how to do this. Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Please provide more stack trace of the error. The context you've given doesn't help much.

Comment: I am afraid, that is the only stack trace I have. However I have solved the problem and will post a solution shortly

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'disabling SSL'? Disabling hostname verification? Disabling SSL trust validation? Disallowing https protocol schema altogether?

Comment: https protocol scheme

Comment: Oleg, I want to trust each and every SSL cert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `#setConnectionManager` call overrides `#setSSLContext` rendering the `SSLContext` instance ineffective.

Either let `HttpAsyncClientBuilder` create a connection manager internally

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
        .loadTrustMaterial(null, (x509Certificates, s) -> true)
        .build();

HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
        .setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
        .setSSLContext(sslContext)
        .build();
```

Or pass the `SSLContext` instance to `PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager` as a constructor argument.

```
SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
        .loadTrustMaterial(null, (x509Certificates, s) -> true)
        .build();

Registry<SchemeIOSessionStrategy> registry = RegistryBuilder.<SchemeIOSessionStrategy>create()
    .register("http", NoopIOSessionStrategy.INSTANCE)
    .register("https", new SSLIOSessionStrategy(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE))
    .build();

DefaultConnectingIOReactor ioReactor = new DefaultConnectingIOReactor();
HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create()
        .setConnectionManager(new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(ioReactor, registry))
        .build();
```

Comment: Hi Oleg, the constructor for `PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager` accepts a `Registry<SchemeIOSessionStrategy>` As opposed to the previous versions. I have solved it with a similar approach nevertheless thanks for your answer :)